# Change background-color once scrolled with react?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to change the bg color of my navbar div once I scroll down. And if it's already at the top, I want to revert back to the original. I tried doing this following some code I got from a website.

I am using tailwind for CSS and React.

Is there a better way to do this? And is there some kind of fault with this code?

```
export default function Home(props) {

  const [scrollPosition, setScrollPosition] = useState(0);
  const [top, setTop] = useState(true)
  const handleScroll = () => {
    const position = window.scrollY;
    setScrollPosition(position);
    if (scrollPosition == 0) {
      setTop(true)
    } else if (scrollPosition > 10) {
      setTop(false)
    } else if (scrollPosition < 10) {
      setTop(true)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll)
    }
  })

  return (
    <div className={`${top ? 'bg-blue-500' : "bg-red-500"}`}>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: you don't need the scroll position state and add an empty array as your dependency array to your use effect as the second parameter

Comment: everything looks fine, except the part ```scrollPosition > 10 and scrollPosition < 10 ```. I don't understand why you need this part to achieve what you want. You can simply use an ```else``` statement, and set top to false.